# How do I use the #if directive

Tags: if-statement, preprocessor-directive

```
#define String1 1
#define String2 3

#if X == String1
#   include "String1.h"
#elif X == String2
#   include "String2.h"
#else
//no header file to include

#endif
```

my question is the "X" variable (macro) in #if X...
Is X local to this file and is it looking for the macros String1 or String2 to be non 0 value
I am a little fuzzy on pre-compiler directives

Comment: In your code `X` is not defined at all.  You would normally have something like `#define X 1` or `#define X String1` somewhere above in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As @NateEldredge mentioned in comments, `X` would have to be defined to either one of the constants (string1, string2). That statement would check to see if the value of `X` is equal to the value of either  constant (string1, string2).

`X` would be visible in **any** file that `#includes` this file. (Assuming `X` is defined in this file).

To avoid extra `#define` statements you could also do something similar to:

```
#define string1 //comment this line to include string2.h
#ifdef string1
    #include "string1.h"
#else
    #include "string2.h"
#endif
```

This uses only 1 define statement. The `#ifdef` checks only to see that something has been defined, it does **not** care about the value. With a setup like this it's simple to quickly add the define statement while compiling. passing it to GCC or similar with an argument like "-Dstring1" would choose the first header, and no define would include the second.